# Disabling a Button in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

In Swing, we can disable a button like this:

```
JButton start = new JButton("Start");
start.setEnabled(false);
```

Is there anyway to do this with a JavaFX Button?
The user should only be able to press the button once.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Of course. Only related **property has opposite semantic and is called `disabled`**. Which means you can use `setDisable` (not `setDisabled`) and `isDisabled`. Since it is a JavaFX property you can also attach listeners to `disabledProperty`.

Check out the JavaFX documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable(boolean)

Code

```
button.setDisable(false)
```

Comment: There are two properties, which are different: `disable` and `disabled`. `disable` is a writable property which you can set with `setDisable(...)`. `disabled` is a read-only property which is true if `disable` is true, or if `disabled` is true for the parent node in the scene graph. (So setting `disable` will disable the node and all its child nodes.)

Answer (score 11):

You have 2 choices if you want the button disabled you can just

```
Button.setDisable(true);
```

or if you want you can also make it invisible

```
Button.setVisible(false);
```