# Node.setDisable() vs setDisabled() in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

There are two methods available for calling when inheriting from `javafx.scene.Node`: (I am showing off the current 8u66 Oracle implementation)

`setDisable(boolean)`

```
public final void setDisable(boolean value) {
    disableProperty().set(value);
}
```

`setDisabled(boolean)`

```
protected final void setDisabled(boolean value) {
    disabledPropertyImpl().set(value);
}
```

Which one should I call when inheriting from `javafx.scene.Node`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends a bit on the context, but you almost certainly want to call `setDisable(...)`.

In JavaFX, a node is rendered as disabled, and ignores any user input, if its `disable` property is `true`, or if the `disable` property is true *for any ancestor in the scene graph*. The `disabled` property, which is a read-only property for clients of the node, reflects this overall state: i.e. `disabled` is true if and only if `disable` is true for this node or for any of its ancestor (container) nodes.

So to disable a node, you should typically call `setDisable(true);`. In a custom subclass of `Node`, you should only call `setDisabled(true);` to enforce the rule described above. Note that the superclass implementation will already enforce this rule, so unless you are doing something very complex (I can't even really see a use case), you will not need to call `setDisabled(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

> You want to use `setDisable`, not `setDisabled`. `setDisable` is a
>   `public` method for disabling a node, `setDisabled` is a `protected`
>   method used only by internal implementations.

Quoted from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871329#comment26095899_17871418) by user [@jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea).