# How to maniupulate the population of the Controls in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have this view designed via *Scene Builder* for JavaFX. There are 4 `ComboBox` in it. I would like to have the possibility to have something to let the user choose how many and which ComboBox use.
For example, my aim is having 3 modes:

1. allow the user to use all the 4 `ComboBox`;
2. allow the user to use only one `ComboBox` and let him choose it;
3. allow the user to use only two `ComboBox` and let them choose the preferred combination of the four `Controls`

Any design or idea (and its implementation) are well welcomed since I am not having a very good solution at this moment. I was thinking something like using the `CheckBox` element near to every `ComboBox` to enable or disable them, but anyway it is not very good. Also I was thinking about putting 3 `Buttons` to select the 3 modes and dynamically populate my `Container`, but I do not know where to start with the implementation.

Comment: `RadioButton`s? Adding a "clear" button next to each `ComboBox` and complaining when none or 3 of the combos have been assigned a value (or disabling the commit button in this case).

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip, but what do you mean for clear button? maybe not selected? in addition how can i pair them to be together and put some conditions on their selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let the user select a specific `ComboBox`, you can enable it using the JavaFX function `setDisable()` that is on all classes that inherit from the `Node` class.

(See difference between: [setDisabled() vs setDisable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374501/node-setdisable-vs-setdisabled-in-javafx))

In the case below, I bind the `disabledProperty()` to the inverse `selectedProperty()` on each `CheckBox`. This way you can select specific ComboBoxes to choose from. Hopefully this will get you started on seeing how JavaFX bindings work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        HBox hBox1 = generateComboBoxHBox();
        HBox hBox2 = generateComboBoxHBox();
        HBox hBox3 = generateComboBoxHBox();
        HBox hBox4 = generateComboBoxHBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox1, hBox2, hBox3, hBox4);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Create 4 of the same HBoxes for an example. Each HBox has a checkbox and combobox
    private HBox generateComboBoxHBox(){
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"));

        comboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());

        hBox.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, comboBox);
        return hBox;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have implement a solution using your `comboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());` as starting point. Do you have an idea on how to make the user select only 1, 2 or 4 checkbox?

Comment: So you only want them to select a pre-determined # of checkboxes? In your example, the user wouldn't be allowed to check 3 checkboxes? I'd have to give it more thought, but I can't think of an easy way to select 4 but not 3. If you're only allowing them to select the 1st, 2nd and 4th, checkbox, then you can do `checkBox3.setDisabled(true)` (you'd have to change the method where you generate the checkbox if you use mine).  But then that begs the question whether or not you need a checkbox for the 3rd one. Hope this gets the creative juices flowing!