# JavaFX ListView performance issue

Tags: java, javafx

So I have a ListView defined in FXML

```
<ListView fx:id="editRecipeList" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0"
       onMouseClicked="#recipeEditListViewOnMouseClicked" prefHeight="406.0"
 prefWidth="242.0" />
```

And a corresponding method

```
@FXML
protected void recipeEditListViewOnMouseClicked() {
    System.out.println("method started");
    List<Document> recipesForEditingClick = mongoDatabase.getCollection("recipes")
            .find(eq("name", "somethng");

   //etc
}
```

The method is not very big, but the first line of code `System.out.println()` executes only after **5 SECONDS**! But in the other ListView in the same program there is no speed problem with the ListView? How could it be? If any other information needed, please, comment

Comment: You could make a [synchronized block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) if that is sufficient or you can [disable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871329/disabling-a-button-in-javafx) the listview and re-enable at the end of the method.

Comment: If the method call takes any appreciable time to execute, you should move it to a background thread anyway, else the UI is simply going to be non-responsive while the method is executing. If you use a [`Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) then you can just check if it is running, and ignore the mouse click if it is. Or you can just disable the list view before you start and enable it again afterwards - but note this will have no effect if you don't move the blocking call to a background thread.

Comment: sorry, guys I'm new here and I don't know if it's ok, but I've changed the topic of the question a bit. I've figured out just to `editRecipeList.setDisable(true);` and after method is done I change value to false. Anyway I thought it was a database performance issue, but it's JavaFX issue

Comment: I kind of doubt that. If you comment out the database access (maybe just create some hardcoded data) do you still see the delay? You're probably either seeing the JVM re-ordering code execution (which it can do if it doesn't affect the end result) or an artifact of your environment. What happens if you put the database call into a `Task`?

Comment: yes, with database commented it works fine. but with the other method database woks fast. I have no idea what's wrong -_-

Comment: by the way, collection in the database(it's MongoDB) consist of only one document

Comment: Then, obviously, it is the database call that is taking the time. You need to do that in a background thread. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call to the database takes any appreciable amount of time, you need to put it into a background thread. The best way to do this in JavaFX is to encapsulate the call in a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Try:

```
@FXML
protected void recipeEditListViewOnMouseClicked() {
    System.out.println("method started");

    editRecipeList.setDisable(true);
    Task<List<Document>> getRecipesTask = new Task<List<Document>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Document> call() throws Exception {
            return mongoDatabase.getCollection("recipes")
                    .find(eq("name", "somethng");
        }
    };

    getRecipesTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        editRecipeList.setDisable(false);
        List<Document> recipesForEditingClick = getRecipesTask.getValue();
        // process results here...

        //etc
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(getRecipesTask);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```